# How do I import data from Activie directories through LDAP URL

Tags: java, web-services, ldap

I have got a requirement to connect Active directory systems through LDAP URL. I need to start this development very easiest way and looking to deliver this ASAP. Kindly share your thoughts.

I will be using Oracle JDeveloper for this development.

Comment: You need to connect to Active Directory from Java application or link/interconnect two different Active directory systems?

Comment: From Java application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pure java example:

http://www.adamretter.org.uk/blog/entries/LDAPTest.java

If you can use Spring, go with spring-ldap:

http://projects.spring.io/spring-ldap/

Spring is really good library to handle ActiveDirectory connectivity. Just read the manual thats all.

Comment: This information is sufficient to move forward. Thanks smajilo.